# Cauchy theorem for triangle

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation

In my notes, we have defined Cauchy's theorem from Complex analysis in 3 versions, the first of which is:

---

Let $\varphi$ be a regular Jordan curve per parts $C^1$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuous on $\overline{{\rm Int}\varphi}$ and holomorphic on ${\rm Int}\varphi$, then
$$\int_\varphi f(z){\rm d}z=0$$

---

We then formulate a side theorem which we call Cauchy for triangle:

---

Let $M\subset\mathbb{C}$ is a closed nondegenerate triangle and $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic on some open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ such that $M\subset\Omega$. Let $\varphi$ is regular Jordan curve per parts $C^1$ which parametrizes $\partial M$. Then:
$$\int_\varphi f(z){\rm d}z=0$$

---

And then we prove this by making small triangles in the big one and then smaller etc... My question is, why do we need to prove this at all. Isn't this a direct consequence of the Cauchy above? Because $\varphi$ is a regular Jordan curve, it is inside a set on which $f$ is holomorphic, then it has to be holomorphic on ${\rm Int}\varphi$ actually, it is holomorphic even on $\overline{{\rm Int}\varphi}$ iand thus it should immediately follow from the 1st statement.

I must be making some mistake in my understanding (maybe with the fact that it is holomorphic?

An additional question, can a triangle be open? (because in the second statement we require that a triangle be closed...

Comment: At the vertices of the triangle the curve is not regular.

Comment: The vertices of the triangle are not an issue, as your curve is only required to be piecewise differentiable. Indeed the first theorem implies the second theorem, but I bet you have not proven the first one at this point. The general strategy to prove it is usually to first consider the weaker form (just for triangles) and use this to prove the stronger version (for any sets bounded by a piecewise differentiable curve).

Comment: Note how it is not complicated to prove those when $f$ is assumed analytic (so that it has an analytic anti-derivative)

Comment: Maybe the triangle version is a Lemma towards the general version.